# Ember.js TypeError: parent is null

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to assign a variable to a controller, initially set to `null`, and then display a conditional a template based on this variable.

Here's my route definition:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        controller.set('suggestion', null);
    }
});
```

And here's part of my `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{log suggestion}}
    {{#if suggestion}}
        <p>There is a suggestion</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>NO suggestion</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

However, the above generates a `TypeError: parent is null` and nothing else happens. If I remove the conditional, everything works.

What's the problem and what does that error refer to? Lastly, how can I get more context for such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your error -- what Ember version are you using?

http://jsbin.com/sodogufabe/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Use the built-in Chrome developer console for debugging errors, there's also an [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) extension for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, the error came from another part. But I have no idea why removing those specific lines made it work. Is there a way to successfully debug Ember apps?...